# How to number elements in a list of string and return a new list?

Tags: python, string, list

So I have a list of strings. I want to create a new list of string which turns the same string into a new string and name it "A". If there's a different string in the list, name it "B" and so on.
If the string is:

```
['F4','A3','F4','B5','A3','K2']
```

Then it should give me a result of:

```
['A','B','A','C','B','D']
```

I don't know how to start the code and can only think of something like a dictionary.

```
dict = {}
result = []
for line in list1:
    if line not in dict:
       dict.update({line:str(chr(65+len(dict)))})
result.append(dict.get(line))
```

Then I don't know how to continue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can make an iterator of [ascii upper-case](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) strings and pull them off one-at-a-time in a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) constructor. One you have that, it's just a list comprehension. Something like:

```
import string
from collections import defaultdict

keys = iter(string.ascii_uppercase)
d = defaultdict(lambda: next(keys))

l = ['F4','A3','F4','B5','A3','K2']

[d[k] for k in l]
# ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

mapping = {}
offset = 0

for item in l:
    if item in mapping:
        continue
    mapping[item] = string.ascii_uppercase[offset]
    offset += 1

[mapping.get(item) for item in l]
```

Output

```
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am new to python so I don't know what does" import string" do here. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: The ```string``` module is part of the python standard library. You import it to be able to access ```ascii_uppercase```, which is an iterable of uppercase letters.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a simple class to store the running results:

```
import string
class L:
   def __init__(self):
      self.l = {}
   def __getitem__(self, _v):
      if (val:=self.l.get(_v)) is not None:
        return val
      self.l[_v]= (k:=string.ascii_uppercase[len(self.l)])
      return k


l = L()
vals = ['F4','A3','F4','B5','A3','K2']
result = [l[i] for i in vals]
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D']
```